# Exporting images to jsPDF from html

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I have a webpage on which I wish to print some HTML.
To do so, I use `html2canvas` and `jsPDF`.

The issue that I encounter is that it does not print the images shown in the HTML.

My HTML and css looks as follows ([complete code in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/methgaard/rd83b07v/)):

```
.handsomeHtml {
 background: red;
}

.crazyFrog {
 background: url('http://e-cdn-images.deezer.com/images/artist/01eb92fc47bb8fb09adea9f763bb1c50/500x500.jpg');
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js">
</script>

<div id="someHtml" class="handsomeHtml">
  Hello, handsome HTML
 <br>
 <img class="crazyFrog"></img>
</div>

 <button id="savePDFbutton" onclick="savePDF()">
  save pdf
 </button>
```

Expected result:

[image]

Actual PDF result

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this working code.

You can check code on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vks9009/c217h0vd/) also.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var testDivElement = document.getElementById('someHtml');

            function savePDF() {
                var imgData;
                html2canvas($("#someHtml"), {
                    useCORS: true,
                    onrendered: function (canvas) {
                        imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                           'image/png');
                        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
                        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
                        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
                        window.open(imgData);
                    }
                });
            }


        </script>
        <style>
            .handsomeHtml {
                background: red;
            }

            .crazyFrog {
                background: url('http://e-cdn-images.deezer.com/images/artist/01eb92fc47bb8fb09adea9f763bb1c50/500x500.jpg');
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="someHtml" class="handsomeHtml">
            Hello, handsome HTML
      <br />
            <img class="crazyFrog"></img>
        </div>
        <br />
        <button id="savePDFbutton" onclick="savePDF()">
            save pdf
        </button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The image is clipped. Why is that?

Comment: it's clipped because when you scrolled down to the "save pdf" button, you're only seeing the clipped size of the image.  if you make the JSFiddle's HTML rendered box larger, you'll be able to print the whole image to pdf

Answer (score 4):

It might be that the jsPDF library cannot resolve images "over the wire", have you attempted to include it as a base64-encoded image directly in the CSS instead?

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked, but I'm afraid that i cannot convert everything to base64

Comment: you can use base 64 encoder utility for concurrent use