# While converting html to pdf using jspdf <img> tag is not working only text gets converts

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jspdf

Have conveted html to pdf  tag does not get converted to pdf in jsPDF can anyone help . How to convert images in  to pdf .Have included the my script below

```
        function savePDF() {
var options = {
  "background": '#000',
  format: 'PNG',
  pagesplit: true
}
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');

var specialElementHandlers = {
  '#content': function(element, renderer) {
    return true;
  }
};
pdf.fromHTML($('#content').get(0), 15, 15, {
  'width': 170,
  'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});

pdf.save('next.pdf');
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting images to jsPDF from html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45160074/exporting-images-to-jspdf-from-html)

Comment: Is it possible to do without html2canvas only with jsPDF